# F# map/set comprehensions

Tags: python, f#, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm looking for something akin to the dict/list/set comprehensions in Python. In Python you can do:

```
[x+2 for x in list if x > 10]
```

and in F#

```
[for x in list do if x > 10 yield x+2]
```

but in Python, you can also do:

```
{x+2 for x in list if x > 10}
```

to generate Sets, and

```
{k: (v+10)/2 for k, v in list.items() if k > 5}
```

to generate Dicts. Is there any equivalent (both in terms of function and in terms of overall tidyness) syntax for this sort of thing in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `set` function accepting `seq<_>`, so you can do:

```
set [for x in list do if x > 10 yield x+2]
```

Same with `dict`. Here are the relevant docs:

`set`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353747.aspx
`dict`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Essentially F# does not have a special syntax for this but you can use array or list comprehension and pass the result to functions provided to the standard library.

```
let intSet = set [for x in list do if x > 10 yield x+2]


let intMap = dict [for (x, y) in list do if x > 10 yield (x,y+2)]
```